# Unwanted ngClick gets fired in IE11 browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

We have written customised checkbox which has divs for square and label.

Issue:Checkbox div has ng-click which should only be fired when clicked on square box but it also get fired if I click on Text next to it in IE11 Version 11.0.9600.16428.

Our implementation is working fine in Chrome and Mozilla but gives above issue when executed in IE11.

Sample Code link: (Please run this code in Chrome & IE11)

http://jsbin.com/luzogucasi/5/edit?html,js,output
Please help.

I have also raised issue in [github](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10980)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is only expected behavior, because you used `for="k"`.
The for attribute will target the `id="k"`, and whenever you clicked on label it will focus element with `id="k"` which you mention in `for` attribute.

Remove attribute `for="k"` from label will work proper on each browser.

HTML

```
<div>
    <div id="k" ng-click="userClicked()" class="disp">

        <div class="check-no"></div>
        <div class="check-yes" ng-show="checked"></div>

    </div>
    <label class="disp label">
        {{checkText}}
    </label>
</div>
```

> **NOTE**
>
> This is not angular related issue

[**JS BIN**](http://jsbin.com/gikixehazi/1/edit?html,js,output)

Hope this could help you, Thanks.